# Tenses - using the word "had" in a sentence

Tags: tenses

Is this passage grammatically correct:

Graham had once called him a coward. It came out one night after they had both been drinking. The next day his friend apologised profusely, but Austin knew that he was right.

Should there be another "had" in the third sentence between "friend" and "apologised"?

Thanks!

Comment: Explain why you think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a close look at the chronological order of the events, it will become obvious to you that ***had apologised*** would not be accurate.

In the order the events occurred, we have:

1. Graham *had* once *called* him a coward.
2. It *came out* one night after they *had* both *been drinking* *(where "had been drinking" is included in the duration of "one night")*
3. The next day his friend apologised profusely, but Austin knew that he was right *(where **apologised** is included in the duration indicated by the verb **knew**)*.

Therefore, since ***apologised*** occurred after ***came out*** and is included in the duration of ***knew***, the use of ***had apologised*** is not justified.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm currently writing a short story and am forever at sixes and sevens when it comes to tenses... I don't suppose you, or anyone else, could recommend a good site concerning the rules for such stuff...

Comment: Have a look at this link from [guidetogrammar](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/sequence.htm), it is a good start, and it includes some other links that might help you. [BBc Learn English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/intermediate/unit-20/tab/grammar) is another reliable source.

Comment: @BobbyM You might say that the perfect is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "the next day"